# How to Force fsck for all other non-root partitions

Tags: linux, rhel, fstab, reboot, fsck

We have the following disks and there mount point:

```
/dev/sdb /appTdb/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdc /appTdb/sdd ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sdd /appTdb/sde ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
/dev/sde /appTdb/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0
```

We want to enable `fsck` on disks - sdb - sde , ( I mean to run fsck during boot )
so we set "1" in this `fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb /appTdb/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1
/dev/sdc /appTdb/sdd ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1
/dev/sdd /appTdb/sde ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1
/dev/sde /appTdb/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1
```

first question - is it correct

second what are the ether values that we can set instead "1" ,

for example 3 or 4 etc ( and what each value mean ? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the numbers are just the order which disks get scanned before others.  So, if 1 is used for all disks, then all the disks have the same priority for scanning.  If one disk fails, then the boot fails, but it could be any of the disks that causes the failure.  Using, say, 2 on some of the disks will cause those disks to be scanned after the ones given a 1.  e.g.

`/dev/sdb /appTdb/sdc ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1
/dev/sdc /appTdb/sdd ext4 defaults,noatime 0 2
/dev/sdd /appTdb/sde ext4 defaults,noatime 0 2
/dev/sde /appTdb/sdb ext4 defaults,noatime 0 3`

In this case, disk /dev/sdb will be scanned first, then /dev/sdc and /dev/sdd, and finally /dev/sde.  This could make a difference in your boot sequence, for example if /dev/sdb was the boot drive.  A failure there would be a problem, whereas a failure on the the other drives could potentially be ignored if not critical.

Incidentally, why are your drives and mount points messed up?  Usually, they match so that it is mentally easier to map mount point to device.

Comment: If you are already at the point of scanning in the boot process, it doesn't really matter if /dev/sdb contains boot or not. I'd be more woried about the root fs.

Comment: Hi, @Tim.  It is fairly normal for extN filesystems to fsck after a period of time or after a number of reboots.  A crash may also force an fsck, at which point having a boot disk that is readable is more important that anything else in bringing the machine up.  So your comment is difficult to comprehend.  I rarely use the extN filesystems anymore, so cannot comment on how the latest incarnations of extN respond to crashes or the like.  Most journaling filesystems rarely fsck, even after a crash.